# javascript code works in Firefox and IE but not Chrome. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As the title suggests, this works everywhere except in Chrome, and I would like to fix it, if possible. The user can select a colour from the drop down box and it is saved in a cookie, for next load. But in Chrome the drop down box isn't working. The code passed the Validator text.

Anyway, if you could help, that would be great.

```
      <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content=en-us>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Background Color selection</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form onsubmit="return false;" action="">
    <p><select name="color_select" size="1" onchange="return setColor(this, global_name)">
      <option style="background-color: aliceblue;" value="aliceblue">aliceblue (#F0F8FF)</option>
      <option style="background-color: antiquewhite;" value="antiquewhite">antiquewhite (#FAEBD7)</option>
      <option style="background-color: aqua;" value="aqua">aqua (#00FFFF)</option>
      <option style="background-color: aquamarine;" value="aquamarine">aquamarine (#7FFFD4)</option>
      <option style="background-color: azure;" value="azure">azure (#F0FFFF)</option>
      <option style="background-color: beige;" value="beige">beige (#F5F5DC)</option>

    </select>&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Delete Cookie"
     onclick="delCookie(global_name); return getColor(color_select, global_name)"></p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//
    var global_name = 'color';
    //
    function getColor(sel, cookie_name) {
        var cookie_value = getCookie(cookie_name);
        if (!cookie_value) cookie_value = 'white';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = cookie_value;
        var opt = sel.options;
        var x, len = sel.length;
        for (x=0; x<len; x++) {
            if (opt[x].value == cookie_value) {
                opt[x].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    getColor(document.forms[0].color_select, global_name);
    //
    function setColor(sel, cookie_name) {
        var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var oneYear = 365 * oneDay;
        var expDate = new Date();
        expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + oneYear);
        setCookie(cookie_name, opt, expDate);
        return getColor(sel, cookie_name);
    }
    // ---------------------------------------- //
    function getCookie(name) {
      var arg = name + "=";
      var alen = arg.length;
      var clen = document.cookie.length;
      var i = 0;
      while (i < clen) {
        var j = i + alen;
        if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
          return getCookieVal (j);
        i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
        if (i == 0) break;
      }
      return null;
    }
    function getCookieVal(offset) {
      var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
      if (endstr == -1)
        endstr = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
    }

    function setCookie(name, value) {
      var argv = setCookie.arguments;
      var argc = setCookie.arguments.length;
      var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
      var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
      var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
      var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) + 
         ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) + 
         ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +  
         ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +    
         ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
    }

    function delCookie(name) {
      exp = new Date();
      exp.setTime(exp.getTime() - (24*60*60*1000));
      var cval = getCookie(name);
      cval = (cval == null) ? "" : cval;
      document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
    }

    //-->
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in your browser's developer console? Describe exactly what doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/zsf7S/, background changes color with selection on Chrome. What is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe cookies are disabled or some extension is interfering in op's Chrome browser? The above code works for me.

Comment: I hate Lazy - I'm not getting any errors in console. German - your jsfiddle code works ok for me, looking at it in Chrome, and then when I paste your code into a new html file it doesn't work, in Chrome. Oleg - I have all cookies enabled in my settings.Tell you what - I'll go to another computer and see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As demonstrated by [Germán Enríquez's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsf7S/), the code works in Google Chrome (at least in version 24.0 beta).

I can suggest two things:

1. Disable Google Chrome's extensions by navigating to chrome://extensions/ - one of them might be interfering somehow.
2. Navigate to chrome://settings/content and enable cookies if they are disabled.

Also, you said that the code had passed the validation. For starters, an HTML page requires a doctype, so sorry, but it doesn't pass. You can try it yourself here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Also, try linting your JavaScript code at http://www.jslint.com/ you will be surprised how many troubles it will find in your code. For example, `var argv = setCookie.arguments;` is not the best way to access the function's arguments and will surely break under strict mode. Also, your `exp = new Date();` statement leaks the `exp` variable into the global scope.

If this doesn't help, please provide more details about the issue and we will answer accordingly.

### UPDATE

I've just noticed that you mentioned in the comments that you're copying the HTML into a file and opening it in the browser. Are you accessing your file with `file://`? If so, that could be the reason why Chrome is causing you problems. Actually, Google Chrome:

> ... intentionally disables cookies on file://, for a variety of reasons...

That's a **WontFix issue 535 in Chrome** since 2008, see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535

Try running a local server and opening the file via `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: Thanks for that Oleg. In fact, when I was trying to hone in on the problem by deleting code I removed:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> so that must be how it passed the validation.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris Yeah, figured it might be the case. Still, I urge you to take a look at JSLint (or JSHint, whatever you like better). Also, I've updated my answer with more information that could be useful to you.

Comment: Hi Oleg. How do I open a file by localhost, like you say? I typed it in the browser followed by xampp - that's what it said was the folder, when I checked in Google, but no joy. In any case, I'm sure you've solved my problem! It must be because of the default Chrome set up when dealing with cookies - just weird the way the only colour I could pick was 'white', when tested on all computers with Chrome, and Firefox and IE is fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris I've never worked with xampp, but here's what you can try: locate the xampp\htdocs folder on your filesystem (could be on C:\ if you're on Microsoft Windows), place your html file into it and visit `http://localhost/xampp/yourfilename.html`

Comment: Cheers Oleg! Bit annoying in Stack Overflow the way you have to write at least 15 characters when 'Cheers Oleg!' is all I wanted to say.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris All the best! By the way, if the answer I provided was helpful, you can mark it as accepted so that other StackOverflow users with a similar question can easily find it.

Comment: sorry, only got used to this 'accept answers' lately.